# Getting a list of records who's

Tags: mysql

I would like to have a list of all the players in a sports league who are on a team that only has a single member.

Here is the sql:

```
CREATE  TABLE `formsfiles`.`Teams` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Sharks');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Jets');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Fish');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Dodgers');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Pigs');

CREATE  TABLE `Players` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Team_ID` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Jim', '1');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Tom', '1');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Harry', '2');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Dave', '2');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Tim', '3');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Trey', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Jay', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Steve', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Ziggy', '5');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Chris', '4');
```

The Result should give me:

```
ID         Name
5          Tim
9          Ziggy
```

Not sure how to get them grouped up?

Comment: both formsfiles and players have pk ID,which ID  you want to access..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the players on a team with only one member you can use:

```
select p.id, p.name
from players p
where p.Team_ID in (select Team_ID
                    from players p
                    group by Team_ID
                    having count(Team_ID) = 1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b08d/9)

Edit, you can also use (moving from comment):

```
select max(id) id, max(name) name
from players 
group by team_id
having count(team_id) = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b08d/22)

Comment: This does the job very nicely!  But I have an issue.  For some reason it is taking gigantic amounts of time to process.    Duration of well over 5 minutes on 200,000 records.  Even when the code is running mySQL Workbench on the same server as the database.  Would building a good index help things out?

Comment: @JVMX Do you have any indexes on the table? You should have one on the `team_id`

Comment: Yes players.Team_ID is Indexed.  (Btree)

Comment: @JVMX You can always try one of the following to see if they perform better -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b08d/18

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bluefeet:

this work wonderfully:

I want to post it here in case someone serches itin the future:

```
select max(id) id, max(name) name
from players 
group by team_id
having count(team_id) = 1;
```

Comment: I added this to my answer, I just wanted to be sure the sql fiddle was working for you before I included this.